# Python: running 2 functions together and based on an event in one, the behavior of the the other function changes

Tags: python, concurrency, event-driven

I will give an example: The requirement is in python.

I want to launch 2 fuctions (func1, func2) togther from a main. Each function is a counter.

func1 counts from 0-100 in steps of 1. The count is available in a list.

func2 also counts from 10-100 in steps of 1, except when func1 has counted to 50, func2 starts counting in steps of 2.

I expect to monitor func1 count list from func2.

I could not try since I am not clear on how run functions together nor how to modify the function behavior based on each others events.